# Apache Isis SimpleApp archetype - clean run classpath error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, domain-driven-design, isis

I am trying to run Apache Isis application generated from archetype using this mvn command:

```
mvn archetype:generate  \
-D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype \
-D archetypeArtifactId=simpleapp-archetype \
-D archetypeVersion=1.6.0 \
-D groupId=com.mycompany \
-D artifactId=myapp \
-D version=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
-B
```

I have started the Jetty application server according to this [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF2FRadglpk) in my IntelliJ Idea but I keep getting error when I try to list all "SimpleObjects".

```
Caused by: org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.exceptions.MetaModelException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/store/rdbms/query/QueryToSQLMapper$SQLTableMapping
at org.apache.isis.core.commons.lang.ThrowableExtensions.throwWithinIsisException(ThrowableExtensions.java:60)
at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.interaction.ActionInvocationFacetForInteractionAbstract.internalInvoke(ActionInvocationFacetForInteractionAbstract.java:376)
at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.interaction.ActionInvocationFacetForInteractionAbstract.invoke(ActionInvocationFacetForInteractionAbstract.java:188)
at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.transaction.facets.ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction$1.execute(ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction.java:57)
at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.transaction.facets.ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction$1.execute(ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction.java:54)
at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:201)
at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.transaction.facets.ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction.invoke(ActionInvocationFacetWrapTransaction.java:54)
at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionImpl.execute(ObjectActionImpl.java:342)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.executeAction(ActionModel.java:458)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.load(ActionModel.java:445)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel.load(ActionModel.java:78)
at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:121)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.executeActionHandlingApplicationExceptions(ActionPanel.java:300)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.executeActionOnTargetAndProcessResults(ActionPanel.java:206)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.executeActionAndProcessResults(ActionPanel.java:154)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.buildGui(ActionPanel.java:93)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanel.<init>(ActionPanel.java:78)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionPanelFactory.createComponent(ActionPanelFactory.java:49)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.viewer.registries.components.ComponentFactoryRegistryDefault.createComponent(ComponentFactoryRegistryDefault.java:129)
at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.widgets.cssmenu.ActionLinkFactoryAbstract$1.onClick(ActionLinkFactoryAbstract.java:103)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:86)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:123)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:633)
... 41 more
```

Is there any other dependence to be added after generating the project from the archetype?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any other dependencies, but one question: did you set up the datanucleus enhancer tasks correctly?  This is usually the issue.  See the [Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org/intro/getting-started/ide/intellij.html) website for more details.

You might also want to subscribe to our [users mailing list](http://isis.apache.org/support.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer Dan. I checked the datanucleus enhance task, and it seemed to be set up correctly. Mysteriously after few re-runs the project started to work properly. I still didn't find out why :).

Comment: Come and subscribe on the Isis users mailing list and we can take it up there.  If necessary, we could arrange a TeamViewer or similar session to get you started; contact me offlist.